# How to send and receive data from serial port for server side in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, serial-port, server-side

I am trying to developing a program with asp.net mvc 5 that sends and receives commands from the serial port on the server side. Actually, I have a piece of hardware that is connected to the server and I want to send command to this hardware and get a Response from that.

This is the method I use to send the data :

```
public static void SendData(string data )
{
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort(
    "COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);


    port.Open();


    port.Write(data);




    port.Close();
}
```

and this is my receive method:

```
public static void ReceiveData()
    {
        if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
            port.Close();
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);


        port.Open();


    }
    public static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int dataLength = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        int nbrDataRead = port.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
        if (nbrDataRead == 0)
            return;


        Taxi.Controllers.ReceiveController.Decision(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

    }
```

I have a problem with my receive method. Every time my hardware sends string, I can just see last character of them in my Index view.
I am wondering how I could create a receive method that receives all characters of posted string.

Comment: Please provide code you have tried so far to help others better answer your question.

Comment: i think that ... i am so close to Answer. i am working on this article https://web.archive.org/web/20130709121945/http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx

Comment: Hold tight for an answer from me later on today.

Comment: ha ha ha... so funny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my answer finally.
this is about Interference on send speed in serial port and receive(calculate) speed in server !
you should set sleep time in first line of "port_DataReceived" method, as you see:

```
public static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        int dataLength = port.BytesToRead;
        char[] result = new char[dataLength];

        for (int len = 0; len < result.Length;)
        {


            len += port.Read(result, len, result.Length - len);
        }
        string send = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            send += result[i];
        }

        Taxi.Controllers.ReceiveController.Decision(send);  

    }
```